# How to calculate ratios of cross sections?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, elementary-particles

I am a first year physics student taking an introductory course in particle physics. For the exercises below, I need to calculate the ratio of cross sections. I believe my understanding of cross sections is good enough, only I do not know how to calculate the answer to such an exercise. As far as I know, the coupling constant $\alpha$ has different values for the EM and the weak force, which might be useful in the second and third exercise. That would imply the answer to the first exercise is equal to 1. Any help is appreciated :) [image: Exercise Image]

Comment: So what have you tried? Certainly you've had to calculate a given cross section before right?

Comment: I know that the strong force, weak force, and EM force all have a different coupling constant. For the first exercise the Feynman diagrams are similar, and coupling constants are the same, so I suspect the ratio to be 1. Is that the right way to go about a problem like this?

Comment: 1. You got it. 2. There is a difference of charges at one vertex. How do they enter in the cross section? 3. Having determined that, add the disjoint possibilities your problem details for you. What do you find? Why are you stuck? Show your work.